# Error capturing table in emacs24

Tags: emacs, emacs24

I have the following text that I want to capture as a table:

```
question,answer
id,id
content,question_id
,content
```

I use `M-x table-capture` with

row delimiter: `,`

column delimiter: newline (`C-q C-j`)

On running this, emacs raises the following error:

`downcase: Symbol's value as variable is void: collection`

I cant figure out whats wrong. Any help would be much appreciated.

-- Edit --

phils suggested turning debug on. The error reported is:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable collection)
  completing-read("Justify (default left): " (("left") ("center") ("right")) nil t nil table-capture-justify-history "left")
  (downcase (completing-read (format "Justify (default %s): " default) (quote (("left") ("center") ("right"))) nil t nil (quote table-capture-justify-history) default))
  (intern (downcase (completing-read (format "Justify (default %s): " default) (quote (("left") ("center") ("right"))) nil t nil (quote table-capture-justify-history) default)))
  (if (and (string= col-delim-regexp "") (string= row-delim-regexp "")) (quote left) (intern (downcase (completing-read (format "Justify (default %s): " default) (quote (("left") ("center") ("right"))) nil t nil (quote table-capture-justify-history) default))))
  (let* ((completion-ignore-case t) (default (car table-capture-justify-history))) (if (and (string= col-delim-regexp "") (string= row-delim-regexp "")) (quote left) (intern (downcase (completing-read (format "Justify (default %s): " default) (quote (("left") ("center") ("right"))) nil t nil (quote table-capture-justify-history) default)))))
  (list (mark) (point) (setq col-delim-regexp (read-from-minibuffer "Column delimiter regexp: " (car table-col-delim-regexp-history) nil nil (quote table-col-delim-regexp-history))) (setq row-delim-regexp (read-from-minibuffer "Row delimiter regexp: " (car table-row-delim-regexp-history) nil nil (quote table-row-delim-regexp-history))) (let* ((completion-ignore-case t) (default (car table-capture-justify-history))) (if (and (string= col-delim-regexp "") (string= row-delim-regexp "")) (quote left) (intern (downcase (completing-read (format "Justify (default %s): " default) (quote (... ... ...)) nil t nil (quote table-capture-justify-history) default))))) (if (and (string= col-delim-regexp "") (string= row-delim-regexp "")) "1" (table--read-from-minibuffer (quote ("Minimum cell width" . table-capture-min-cell-width-history)))) (if (and (not (string= col-delim-regexp "")) (string= row-delim-regexp "")) (string-to-number (table--read-from-minibuffer (quote ("Number of columns" . table-capture-columns-history)))) nil))
  (let ((col-delim-regexp) (row-delim-regexp)) (barf-if-buffer-read-only) (if (table--probe-cell) (error "Can't insert a table inside a table")) (list (mark) (point) (setq col-delim-regexp (read-from-minibuffer "Column delimiter regexp: " (car table-col-delim-regexp-history) nil nil (quote table-col-delim-regexp-history))) (setq row-delim-regexp (read-from-minibuffer "Row delimiter regexp: " (car table-row-delim-regexp-history) nil nil (quote table-row-delim-regexp-history))) (let* ((completion-ignore-case t) (default (car table-capture-justify-history))) (if (and (string= col-delim-regexp "") (string= row-delim-regexp "")) (quote left) (intern (downcase (completing-read (format "Justify (default %s): " default) (quote ...) nil t nil (quote table-capture-justify-history) default))))) (if (and (string= col-delim-regexp "") (string= row-delim-regexp "")) "1" (table--read-from-minibuffer (quote ("Minimum cell width" . table-capture-min-cell-width-history)))) (if (and (not (string= col-delim-regexp "")) (string= row-delim-regexp "")) (string-to-number (table--read-from-minibuffer (quote ("Number of columns" . table-capture-columns-history)))) nil)))
  call-interactively(table-capture record nil)
  command-execute(table-capture record)
  smex-read-and-run(("toggle-debug-on-error" "auto-fill-mode" "table-capture" "scratch" "table-justify" "table-insert" "replace-string" "customize-themes" "erc" "grep" "butterfly" "dired" "customize-group" "customize-option" "text-mode" "gist-region" "python-else" "python-mode" "magit-status" "customize-face" "package-install" "replace-rectangle" "diredp-do-bookmark" "ps-print-region-with-faces" "flymake-python-pyflakes-load" "rvm-activate-corresponding-ruby" "cd" "mf" "ri" "5x5" "arp" "dbx" "dig" "ert" "ftp" "gdb" "irc" "jdb" "kbd" "man" "mpc" "pdb" "pwd" "rsh" "sdb" "xdb" "yow" "calc" "dark" "diff" ...))
  smex()
  call-interactively(smex nil nil)
```

-- Edit --

After some debugging, I could conclude the error occurs if I set `(ido-ubiquitous-mode t)` in my emacs init scripts.

Comment: FWIW, it worked for me. Use `M-x toggle-debug-on-error` to check exactly what is failing and where. Also try it in `emacs -Q`.

Comment: @phils, ive updated the question with the output from debug.

Comment: Looks vaguely like the empty first column is the problem.

Comment: @tripleee I tried adding some content to the first column, but the error persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it was because of a [know issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/emacs-snapshot/+bug/1003928) in `ido-ubuquitous`

Answer (score 1):

Like @phils says, start with `emacs -Q`, and give us repro steps with version info.  It's working for me as well with Emacs 24.

Do you have a completion package turned on like ido?

Comment: Yes I do have ido (pun not intended :). I'm using the emacs settings from here: https://github.com/purcell/emacs.d/

Comment: I tried to see what was causing the error, I finally figured out setting `(ido-ubiquitous-mode t)` causes the error.